# Second button Event is not happening in Update panel in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, scriptmanager

I have a aspx page in which i have putted two update panel with two submit buttons one in each...But on clicking second button it is not firing second button event it is taking first button validate message..

Here is my aspx page code....

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updDate1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" style="position: absolute;
    left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 339px; height: 243px;">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <table width="400">
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <b>Sign Up for New User Account</b>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    UserName:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rqfUserName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtUserName"
                        Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Password:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPwd" runat="server" TextMode="Password" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPwd"
                        Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Confirm Password:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCnfPwd" runat="server" TextMode="Password" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordConfirmRequiredValidator" runat="server"
                        ControlToValidate="txtCnfPwd" ForeColor="red" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Required" />
                    <asp:CompareValidator ID="PasswordConfirmCompareValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCnfPwd"
                        ForeColor="red" Display="Dynamic" ControlToCompare="txtPwd" ErrorMessage="Confirm password must match password." />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="Create User" />
                </td>
                <tr>
                    <td class="style1" colspan="3">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblResult" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<div>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updDate2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" RenderMode="Inline"
        style="position: absolute; left: 628px; top: 0px; width: 339px; height: 243px;">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="GridviewDiv">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">
                            &nbsp;
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:GridView ID="gvRoles" runat="server" CssClass="Gridview" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#df5015" />
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRole" runat="server" />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Role Name">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblRole" runat="server" Text="<%#Container.DataItem %>" />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnAssign" runat="server" Text="Assign or UnAssign" OnClick="btnAssign_Click"
                                Style="height: 26px" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <div>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSuccess" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</form>
```

Any help will be highly apprecited..

Thanks In advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dear i tried your code by Making dummy project and it clearly tells me that it's a problem of  `CausesValidation="false"`,I know you tried this thing as well but even i don't know your back end coding.So same suggesstion from my side just change your `btnAssign` like

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAssign" runat="server" Text="Assign or UnAssign" 
Style="height: 26px" onclick="btnAssign_Click" CausesValidation="false" />
```

*Note :- Try to check it in different browser as well.*

Also try for `ValidationGroup` as well.
Apply `ValidationGroup` property into your validation control and also assign that same property to `btnSubmit`.This will work.

Hope it works.

Answer (score 2):

Set `CausesValidation="false"` in the second button

Answer (score 2):

Setting  `CausesValidation="false"` in the second button should have worked.

One another way to get this work is to assign a common `ValidationGroup` to your Validators as well as to your first Submit button [only of UpdatePanel `updDate1` ].

For e.g. in your Validators:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rqfUserName" runat="server"
     ControlToValidate="txtUserName"Display="Dynamic"
     ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red"
     ValidationGroup="updDate1UserCreation" />
```

And your submit button with ID:`btnSubmit`

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server"
     OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="Create User"
     ValidationGroup="updDate1UserCreation" />
```

Your first updatePanel will finally look like:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updDate1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"
    style="position: absolute;
    left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 339px; height: 243px;">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <table width="400">
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <b>Sign Up for New User Account</b>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    UserName:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rqfUserName" runat="server"
                         ControlToValidate="txtUserName"
                         Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red"
                         ValidationGroup="updDate1UserCreation" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Password:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPwd" runat="server" TextMode="Password" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1"
                         runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPwd"
                         Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red"
                         ValidationGroup="updDate1UserCreation" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Confirm Password:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCnfPwd" runat="server" TextMode="Password" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordConfirmRequiredValidator"
                           runat="server"
                           ControlToValidate="txtCnfPwd" ForeColor="red" 
                           Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Required"
                           ValidationGroup="updDate1UserCreation" />
                    <asp:CompareValidator ID="PasswordConfirmCompareValidator"
                         runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCnfPwd"
                         ForeColor="red" Display="Dynamic" ControlToCompare="txtPwd"
                         ErrorMessage="Confirm password must match password."
                         ValidationGroup="updDate1UserCreation" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server"
                         OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="Create User"
                         ValidationGroup="updDate1UserCreation" />
                </td>
                <tr>
                    <td class="style1" colspan="3">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblResult" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ContentTemplate>

</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: sir what i need to do if it want to load second updatepanel after the first submit button clicked from updatepanel 1

Comment: You can hide and show the updatePanel using the Visible proerty. Set this intially to false. and when you click Submit button, then in submit click handler,  you can try setting it to true